# Using wspbuilder to create a custom STSADM command

Tags: stsadm, wspbuilder

I'm using wspbuilder to create a .wsp package that will deploy a custom stsadm command. I need the .wsp to include an .xml command file:

```
<commands>
<command name="mycustomcommand"....../>
</commands>
```

This file according to technet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417382.aspx needs to be added the the 12/CONFIG folder. I tried adding a 12/CONFIG structure to my project and having the file located there but the .wsp package still does not contain it.

Is there a way of achieving this with the wspbuilder?

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange since it should work. 
Using WSPBuilder you should create your project as follows:

1. Create a new WSP Builder project
2. Add a subfolder to the /12/ folder called Config
3. In the /12/Config folder add a file called **stsadmcommands..xml**. Make sure that it always starts with **stsadmcommands**
4. Add a class and inherit from **ISPStsadmCommand**
5. Implement the interface and your commands
6. Add the commands to the xml file. Make sure to add the fully qualified name including public key token.
7. Build the WSP
8. Deploy the WSP
9. Have fun with your commands...

*Works on my machine*

/WW